# Is it possible for a console application to deny closing with CTRL + C?

Tags: windows, security, cmd.exe, malware, console

When I run a console application (either a .bat or a .exe console application made with a language like Cpp or C# for example) in a shell, I can hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop the operation.

Is it possible for a console application to be immune to <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: The `python` interpeter intercepts Control+C.

Comment: This may be interesting  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There are two ways to do this that I know of.

Method #1: The console application contains a signal handler to prevent the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and other terminating signals. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031542/catch-all-signals-that-would-stop-a-program) one way to do this.

Method #2: You run the program inside of another program that contains the signal handler. I have an example of a signal catcher [here](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/catch.c).

Comment: Oh, I didn't think it was possible to catch the signals thrown by ctrl+C. Always thought it raised sigstop.